# ARIMA(0,0,0) residuals are the same as the timeseries data

Tags: forecasting, arima, residuals, white-noise

I am very new to analyzing and forecasting timeseries data so apologies if this question has an answer too obvious.
I am trying to find the residuals between a stationarized price data and white noise ARIMA(0,0,0).

```
library(forecast)
library(tseries)

DJT = read.csv("DJTA.csv")
DJT_ts <- ts(DJT$DJTA, start=c(2013,1), end=c(2022, 3), frequency=12)
djt_obs1 <- window(DJT_ts, c(2014), c(2019, 1))
djt_obs1_diff <- diff(djt_obs1)
adf.test(djt_obs1_diff) # is stationary

fit1 <- Arima(djt_obs1_diff, order=c(0,0,0)) 
checkresiduals(fit1)
```

When I check the residual plot, I can see that the plot is the same as `djt_obs1_diff`, which (I think) means ARIMA(0,0,0) is computed as a flat line and not white noise? What am I missing here? How can I compute the residual of white noise vs ts data?

Thanks

I am trying to compare the RMSE values (of White Noise vs Actual Price) of different stocks to see if some markets are "more random" than others.

Comment: ARIMA(0,0,0) is a constant (either zero or not, probably zero in your case) plus random noise. This *is* white noise. But white noise is a random process, so if you calculate the difference between your series and a *realization* of white noise, you will get different results each time, which is probably not what you want. And conversely, the expectation of white noise is simply zero. Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: My plan was to calculate the RMSE of stationarized data vs white noise for different stocks at different time intervals, and then conduct ANOVA to see if RMSE is significantly different in one stock - which would mean it is less random than the others. Apologies if my logic is flawed, I'm a student trying to finish up a project. @StephanKolassa